# JavaScript (strict) equality of new String("a") objects

Tags: javascript, comparison

There is in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)
**11.9.1 The Equals Operator (==)**:

> NOTE 3 The equality operator is not always transitive. For example,
>   there might be two distinct String objects, each representing the same
>   String value; each String object would be considered equal to the
>   String value by the == operator, but the two String objects would not
>   be equal to each other. For Example:
>
> - `new String("a") == "a"` and `"a" == new String("a")` are both **true**.
> - `new String("a") == new String("a")` is **false**.

but in **11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm**:

> 7. Return **true** if `x` and `y` refer to the same object. Otherwise, return **false**.

But no, with jsc

```
new String("a")===new String("a")
```

is true.

Is that a jsc.exe error? Or are they the same object? Than why?

Comment: Yes, seems to be a problem with `jsc`. Maybe it does some sort of string pooling, like Java. Not sure what kind of answer you expect though. You better report to the maintainers of the tool.

Comment: I am just new with JS, and I do not know, it is a bug, or a feature?

Comment: I'm guessing jsc.exe is a Microsoft compiler, and it obviously doesn't follow the standard when compiling to an executable, so as Felix said, not much we can do about this, you'll have to report it ?

Comment: Or maybe there is a clear explanation, that I do not see

Comment: Yes, it is the MS compiler. I use it just since two days, and do I found a bug?

Comment: Guys, you're right. I tried it with jsfiddler, it is false. Thanks!

Comment: The jsc compiler is pretty primitive and should not be used (internally uses all sorts of reflection, does not take advantage of DLR, cannot use generics and is not maintained). You could try other implementations of JS on .NET like Jurassic or Jint. Also you could interop with V8 using JavaScript.NET

Answer (score 0):

The operator === in js return true if is equal type and equal value. So is correct that it return true because they are both String object and their value is "a".

Have a look at the documentation http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp